# Postgre divider 0 result

Tags: postgresql, metabase

i have the following data in Metabase
[image]
i tried get the percentage of `do_qty` to `target_lembar`.

i tried to calculate using the following query:

```
select distributor_id
, target_lembar
, do_qty
, do_qty::integer / target_lembar::integer do_qty_divide_target_lembar_percentage
from raw 
where target_lembar>0
```

why did `do_qty_divide_target_lembar_percentage` returns `0`?

what i expect is `28.16%` for `distributor_id=155` in the first row

How do i resolve this?

Thanks!

Update:

It solved by the following query:

```
select distributor_id
, target_lembar
, do_qty
, do_qty::float / target_lembar::float do_qty_divide_target_lembar_percentage
from raw 
where target_lembar>0
```

Comment: What is the datatype of your percentage column? You need a float type, but I suspect you have an integer. You also need to multiply the result of the division by 100 to get a percentage, otherwise you just get a decimal fraction. Which you need will depend on how you're using the value later, and what formatting your presentation layer provides.

Comment: hi @TangentiallyPerpendicular thanks it worked! I've done this before in MySQL and MySQL is able to calculate both integer giving us float results. Thanks!

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer instead of updating the post so that the question won't appear in searches for questions without answers. It's perfectly acceptable to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problems by using the following queries:

```
select distributor_id
, target_lembar
, do_qty
, do_qty::float / target_lembar::float do_qty_divide_target_lembar_percentage
from raw 
where target_lembar>0
```

we have to parse the 2 columns that we want to calculate using the same data type.